# How to add extra price to cart total in magento checkout shipping method step

Tags: magento, field, checkout, cart

I have a custom field in shipping method step in checkout page. I want to add the custom field value with total amount of cart value. So that, custom field value will show with the total amount.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do with the custom extension

as it is working in one of my application to add extre fees on checkout process

just follow step as on

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total

and it will sure help you to solve your issue.

*Above link only for knowledge purpose, i am not associate with any more with above link*

Comment: I am unable to download such extension, so please help me to find out the download link. thanks

Comment: i use this extension for fee works perfect but couponcode stops working any idea